# Question concerning Lawrence C. Evans Partial Differential Equations chapter 6.2.2

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to understand theorem 2 in chapter 6.2.2 of the book "Partial Differential Equations" by Lawrence C. Evans, specifically the part where he proves condition (ii). Near the end of that proof he gets the inequality $$\frac{\theta}{2} \int_U \lvert Du \rvert^2 \text{d}x \leq B[u,u] + C\int_U u^2 \text{d}x.$$
He then asserts that using poincaré's inequality that $$\lVert u \rVert_{L^2} \leq C \lVert Du \rVert_{L^2}$$
with seemingly the same $C$ as before. My first qustion is: Isn't this a mistake? Shouldn't it just be some other constant $K$ and not the same constant $C$?. After that he concludes condition (ii) with no further explanation. My second question is how he gets from these two inequalities to condition (ii).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes I think it should be different constant. It's an abuse of notation since it's just a constant.
2. You combine poincare inequality with the previous result namely
   $$\frac{\theta}2\int_U\mid Du\mid ^2dx\leq B[u,u]+C\int_U u^2dx$$ and use the definition of $H^1_0$ norm of $u$.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain how? Also why cant you just add $\frac{\theta}{2} \int_U u^2 \text{d}x$ to both sides without using poincare? Then you get $\frac{\theta}{2} \lVert u \rVert_{H_0^1(U)}^2 \leq B(u,v) + (\frac{\theta}{2} +C)\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(U)}^2$ which would prove the result.

Comment: Yeah you can also do that. I think this just means that since poincare enables us to control $L^2$ norm of $u$ by $L^2$ norm of $Du$, we do not have to worry about $L^2$ norm of $u$ which we needed to add on the left hand side of the above inequality. This gives a better bound